# Movie: An angel hits a satellite and falls to Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I only remember the opening scene of this movie. From what I remember, an angel hits a satellite and falls to Earth, ending up in a guy's back yard pool. The pool area is strewn with stuff like there had just been a party.

I think it is from the 1980's but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Date With an Angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_with_an_Angel)* (1987)

> *Date with an Angel* tells the story of Jim Sanders, an executive at a cosmetics company, about to marry Patty Winston, the spoiled daughter of Jim's boss. Jim unknowingly has a brain tumor, and his headaches have gotten worse. It is suggested that he will die, and an angel arrives on the scene, given the task of bringing Jim's soul back to heaven on the night of his engagement party.
>
> After his three buddies, George, Don and Rex, kidnap Jim to take him to another celebration at his home, Jim decides that he has had enough of partying and goes to sleep. Jim later awakes to see a bright light illuminating from his apartment's swimming pool--and discovers an angel knocked unconscious after one of her wings was broken due to colliding with an orbiting satellite....

### Trailer

Found with a search for *film angel hits satellite*

Comment: Yeah I think that may be it!